# How to use notifyDataSetChanged with finish()

Tags: android

I have a list view which show list of task, on selecting task it shows details about task, when I delete the particular task it returns to the previous activity by finish(). but it does not update the list.
I want to know how and where to use notifyDataSetChanged method and add adapter method is never used.
Other than notifyDataSetChanged() solution is also accepted :) i just want to update the list when it returns to the previous activity.

Answer (score 1):

Do it with `startActivityForResult()`. When you create intent to open new activity open it for result. The task being deleted is your result. So when it's marked as deleted and you return to your previous activity, the result triggers and you can delete the marked item + call the `notify`.

More info here : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use the notifyDataSetChanged on the onResume method, this always update the data itself when the Activity shows

Answer (score 0):

You can also notify your parent activity before finishing your current activity. You just have to register a Receiver in your main activity and all others activities will be able to notify that activity. You can even send data!

As my english is not that good, sample code : 
The MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// you can define your name for your receiver as a constant,
// so you can access it from other activities if you want
public static final String MY_SUPER_INTERNAL_NOTIFICATION = "MY_SUPER_INTERNAL_NOTIFICATION";
public static final String MY_OBJECT = "my_object";
public static final String MY_OBJECT_POSITION = "my_object_position" ;

private MyCustomAdapter adapter;
private ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    // set up your list with your adapter and data...
    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this);
    // [...] I suppose you know how to do that, I dont write everything
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // when you click on a row from your list,
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    SecondActivity.class
            );

            // you can for example put data in a Bundle and pass it to the other activity
            // then on the onCreate you can use that data as you want
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            // IMPORTANT be sure that the object you are putting in the bundle is Serializable (implements Serializable)
            bundle.putSerializable(MY_OBJECT, adapter.getItem(position));
            // you can also for example send the position of the row you clicked
            bundle.putInt(MY_OBJECT_POSITION, position);

            // put your bundle in the intent
            intent.putExtras(bundle);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // register your Receiver! don't forget to do that or you will never be notified
    LocalBroadcastManager
            .getInstance(this)
            .registerReceiver(
                    broadcastReceiver,
                    new IntentFilter(MY_SUPER_INTERNAL_NOTIFICATION)
            );
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            // get the position sent by the other activity
            int position =  intent
                    .getExtras()
                    .getInt(SecondActivity.MY_EXAMPLE_KEY);

            adapter.deleteItem(position);
        }
    }
};

// adapter class...
private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<MyObject> data;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context) {

    }

    public void deleteItem(int position){
        // delete your item from the list of data
        data.remove(position);
        // dont forget to notify
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public MyObject getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return null;
    }
    // adapter class, you can extend your favorite type of adapter
}
}
```

The SecondActivity class :

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String MY_EXAMPLE_KEY = "EXAMPLE";

private MyObject myObject;
private int myObjectPosition;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

    myObject = (MyObject) getIntent()
            .getExtras()
            .getSerializable(MainActivity.MY_OBJECT);

    myObjectPosition = getIntent()
            .getExtras()
            .getInt(MainActivity.MY_OBJECT_POSITION);

    // do all your stuff with your object
    // before calling finish do this
    beforeFinishDoThisStuff();
}

private void beforeFinishDoThisStuff() {
    sendBroadcastToMainActivity();
    finish();
}

private void sendBroadcastToMainActivity() {
    // create an intent and put your Receiver name as action name
    // like you defined in your MainActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.MY_SUPER_INTERNAL_NOTIFICATION);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    // put whatever you want, here I put just the previous position of the object in the list
    bundle.putInt(MY_EXAMPLE_KEY, myObjectPosition);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    // notify your MainActivity
    LocalBroadcastManager
            .getInstance(this)
            .sendBroadcast(intent);

    // after this finish !
}
}
```

Hope you understand how to notify activities with BroadcastManager. It's very powerful and simple to use.

Have fun coding !